Thousands of Untracked Files After Initial Git Configuration
I've been learning git (so please excuse me if I ask stupid questions!) and just configured it on my laptop (macOS). However, on VS Code thousands of files suddenly popped up in my Changes section, and I have no idea what many of them do:
a snapshot of the first few files in the long list of Changed files
I don't think I should commit all of them to git, but when I try to Discard those changes, VS Code warns me that these untracked files will be "DELETED FROM DISK" and that this action is "IRREVERSIBLE". I don't hope to lose important files, but I'm not sure how to proceed without discarding them (as my VS Code is severely lagging).
If anyone could provide some insights on this, that would be greatly appreciated! Please also let me know if I should provide more information on my situation.

It seems you have initialized your home path as a git repository. Check if the directory ~/.git or /Users/<username>/.git exists. If it does, just remove it.

@ElpieKay Please do not suggest to remove a .git directory; unwary users might think it is a good idea in general and end up without a backup. Suggest to rename it, and when things work out as expected, only then remove it.

You don't initialise git once in your home directory. Instead, you are meant to create or clone one separate git repository in different locations for each project you want to work on, and it's that subdirectory the one you open in your IDE or editor.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+10k
